# Associate file type on specific path

Tags: intellij-idea, smarty

I'm currently working on a Smarty project which for some reason is using the `html`-extension instead of `tpl`, and I'm trying to make IntelliJ associate these files with the Smarty plugin.

Obviously I don't want to associate all HTML files with Smarty, so I've tried:

1. the project path + wildcard (eg. `/Users/Foo/project/templates/*/*.html`)
2. the local path + wildcard (eg. `templates/*/*.html`)
3. The former + `/**/*.html`

... But none of them seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not possible. A file type is determined only by the name of the file, not by its path.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks anyway :-)